# Apache Superset - Auto Registration of User

Tags: flask, apache-superset

I am trying to implement auto registration of users in Apache Superset. While I understand this can be implemented by setting AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION to True my specific use case seems to be a bit different.

What I want to achieve : Only pre-configured users should be able to auto register. I have a org having 1000s of employee and I do not want all the users to be able to have access to my superset but rather employees belonging to my team should have access only, therefore i am looking for ways to pre-configure user in some user store. And if someone arrives at the superset login for the first time they should be able to auto register by providing a password only known to them.

As an alternative, I can also create the user along with the password (like we typically create users in superset), However, when user first login using the password provided by me, they should be forced to change the password.

So far i have been struggling in identifying a proper solution to either of the approaches. Any alternative approaches are also very welcomed.